# Why is there a delay for logging in (wubi)?

Tags: 11.10, wubi, login-screen

I use wubi to install Ubuntu under win7 in partition F which is fat32. When I choose Ubuntu at boot time, it jumps into a window.

It shows two choices:

```
ubuntu
ubuntu recovery
```

After choosing Ubuntu, it shows:

```
error: file not found
error: you need to load kernel first
press any key to continue.
```

It goes back to the choice window after I press a key.

Again I choose Ubuntu, and it goes black and then it comes to the login window. After I log in it works.

My question is:

Is what happens before the login window normal or not (when using wubi)?

Answer (score 1):

This is not normal at all. I would suggest reinstalling, or possibly installing Ubuntu the normal way (since Wubi is really just to give you a chance to see if it works well on your system).